# Test a large wizard flow / enquiry form with specflow

Tags: testing, specflow, gherkin, ui-testing

We are testing a large enquiry form. It's a governmental form, it's large.

It has 5 steps, presented like a wizard, and in step 6 you get an overview what data you entered. Now there are a lot of dependencies, in the step, but also between the steps.

For example
if you choose option 'no' in question 7 in step 1, another two questions come up.

if you choose option 'yes' in question 12 in step 1, another question and textbox come up.

if you choose option 'no' in question 8 in step 1, two extra questions pop up in step 4.
And so on, and on.

So the problem we have is that there is no simple flow. If you want to test step 4, you HAVE to go through step 1,2 and 3, so you have to provide testdata (a lot) also for steps that are needed in this step. So one extra test for step 5 means setting up all the data for step 1,2,3 and 4 too.

If there is new mandatory field in step 1, we have to adjust all the tests to provide a value for that field, otherwise the click 'go to step 2' doesn't work.

Is there a pattern or some other nice way for these kind of forms?

Comment: Could you post a scenario as an example? It doesn't need to be an exact scenario, but I think we need something more concrete before we can answer this question.

Comment: Each step is related to a specific page? Are you using page objects?

Comment: No, this testsuite is without page object. I think the creator has heard of the page object strategy, but there is only one page. But maybe, as I think about it, is correct because there is only one page with 1 giant client side (Angular) wizard.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have enough information to answer your question without at least a representative scenario or two.